# Highscores algorithm will continue adding same user if the next score equals to it

Tags: java, algorithm, loops

I have wrote an algorithm for my game highscores, which is based on kill/death ratio.
Obviously the biggest kill/death ratio will be #1.

It works fine, until It reaches the lowest score, which is 0.0, and I have 100 more players with a 0.0 ratio. The algorithm simply will add the same name with the 0.0 score and will not add rest of the players with 0.0 score after it.

I am not sure why it yet, I hardly remember that I've done there, I am trying to understand:

```
@Override
public ArrayList<TempClient> getResortedHighscores(ArrayList<TempClient> list) {
    ArrayList<TempClient> sorted = new ArrayList<TempClient>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        TempClient max = null;
        for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (max != null) {
                if (list.get(j).getRatio() > max.getRatio() && !sorted.contains(list.get(j))) {
                    max = list.get(j);
                }
                continue;
            }
            max = list.get(j);
        }
        sorted.add(max);
    }
    return sorted;
}
```

What did I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: This is horribly inefficient. Use a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and have Java's `Collections` sort your list.

Comment: Use `Comparator`. Then you can simply compare the `Ratio` - if the `Ratio` is equal then you can check against their names if they are stored in the TempClient.

Comment: @Zyn It's even simpler than that. His compare method just returns `a.geteRatio()-b.getRatio()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Java's [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).

It makes what you are trying to do trivial.

```
public ArrayList<TempClient> getResortedHighscores(ArrayList<TempClient> list) {
    return Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<TempClient>(){
        public int compare(TempClient o1, TempClient o2){
            return o1.getRatio() - o2.getRatio();
        }
    });
}
```

Some quick explanation of what is going on:

Java has a "utility" class called `Collections`:

> This class consists exclusively of static methods that operate on or return collections. It contains polymorphic algorithms that operate on collections, "wrappers", which return a new collection backed by a specified collection, and a few other odds and ends.

The method `sort` from Java's utility `Collections` class has the following signature:

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list,
        Comparator<? super T> c)
```

This means it takes some List of generic objects (`T`), and some `Comparator` for `T` or one of the members of its subclass hierarchy.

`Comparator` is a simple interface with two methods: `compare` and `equals`. Since all objects already have an `equals` method, we don't need to implement one. However, we do need to implement compare:

```
int compare(T o1, T o2)
```

This is pretty easier. If `o1` is greater than `o2`, we need to return a positive integer. If it is less, a negative one, and if they are the same we return `0`. In our case, subtracting the ratios will give us positive, negative, or 0, making things pretty simple.

As a note, this might sort them in ascending order. If this is the case, multiplying by negative one should invert the order (making the list descending).

```
return (o1.getRatio() - o2.getRatio())*-1;
```

Comment: Thanks, used. But what is the difference? I mean how does the comparator work?

Comment: @user3123545 I added an explanation. In order to really understand Java's Collections you'll need to have a good understanding of [`Generics`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)